# 504 Gateway Time Out on Load Testing on Apache Instance

Tags: apache-httpd, performance, aws

I have a Laravel app deployed over Apache Instance
Instance Config is as follows,

```
T3A.2xLarge  (vCPU = 4, Memory 16 GIB)
```

I have increased apache timeout to 600 Seconds, configured `mpm_prefork` as below,

```
    <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
            StartServers            16
            MinSpareServers         0
            MaxSpareServers         0
            MaxClients              16
            ServerLimit             256
            MaxRequestWorkers       400
            MaxConnectionsPerChild  25
    </IfModule>
```

I have also changed the PHP Configuration according.

The RDS DB has a max_connection of 600 so I have configured the maxRequestWorker to 400 to 600 else it is giving me a `Too Many Connection` error.

But along with this configuration when we do load testing for 3000 users per 20 Ramp up period
It gives a `504 Gateway Timeout` Error for Half of the requests.

But when I see other tools and logs for error it doesn't log any error

Any suggestion on configuration?

Answer (score 0):

*Spotting this this specific error is 90% of your reason why you do Load testing.*

Given that you are doing this on AWS I presume you are using an Application Load Balancer.  `504` is often the result of an application not responding fast enough and the load balancer giving up.

You are unlikely to get a log explaining what's causing this.  The application server most likely thinks it's still fine, it's just the load balancer gave up waiting.

I believe the [Connection Idle Timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#connection-idle-timeout) will affect the load balancer's timeout.  This defaults to 60 (much more than 600 you set on the server).  But be aware that leaving a user waiting that long is a pretty bad experience.

Otherwise you need to investigate why the server is running so slow.  You will need to look for a bottleneck that is slowing down the server's responses.  There may be more than one.  This might be:

- A lack of system resources: CPU and / or memory
- disk IO - especially if your are using GP2 EBS - use GP3 instead
- downstream problems, such as RDS responding slow - look for resource issues in RDS etc.
- Locking problems.  For example if the app is making updates to the database, it might be that all the clients are contending.  This might require the app to be fixed.